# How to insert "&xyz" in the body of a mail while using "mail to:" function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, email-attachments, mailto

I have to use `"mailto:?subject=someSubject&body=someBody"` to open a link using `windows.location.href`. In the body i need to give a text like `"&ref=abcd"`. I think the function is treating as another attribute like to,`&subject`,`&body`,etc thus not interpreting it in the mail. Please suggest how to keep the text in the body.
Thanks.

Comment: `/&xyz` would help you

Comment: [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is what you need